# Questions about pagination

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Question 1: paginate on a query
In document I saw we can pass the $query in the paginate function :

```
 $query = $this->Articles->find()->where(['id >' => 10])->limit(1);
 debug($this->paginate($query));
```

The "where" work well
But seem that the "limit(1)" not work.

```
debug($query); // This work for both where & limit
```

Question 2: How can we use paginate in a custom Component?

Answer (score 0):

Use paginate property:

```
$this->paginate = ['limit' => 10];
```